# JMP FF FF FF как будет

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте.

`JMP FF` (JMP SHORT т.е. на один байт) байткод `EB FF`

`JMP FF FF FF FF` (JMP NEAR т.е. на четыре байт) байткод `E9 FF FF FF FF`

Такой вопрос, `JMP` на 3 байтный прыжок как будет?

Comment: Никак: на платформе x86 нет "трехбайтного" режима адресации.

Comment: Хорошо... А как прыгнут тогда?

Comment: Напишите конкретную проблему, которую вы пытаетесь решить. JMP SHORT позволяет прыгать в пределах +- 127 байт, JMP NEAR - +- 2**31 (примерно). Эти байты, которые у вас забиты FF - это фактически смещение относительно конца команды JMP.

Comment: В игре меняю байт код, так как байт код не влезает в одну инструкцию, ищу cave адрес и туда пишу свои байты, как на Cheate Engine. Но, до cave адреса у меня прижок получается скажем 7F8A00  и как на такую расстоянию пригнут?

Comment: `7F8A00` - это адрес (причем четырехбайтный, просто нули в начале не показываются), а для jmp нужно смещение (изменение адреса) от конца команды jmp до нужного места. Если в оригинале там jmp short, а изменение будет больше 127, то прыжок заменить не получится.

Comment: Меня немного не поняли, вот сморите. 7FFBA4B7CEB4 - 83 81 D0010000 01     - add dword ptr [rcx+000001D0],01 { 1 }  это оригнальный байты с CE. Его меняю на JMP 7F8A00 остальные нупом. один нуп влезает на JMP. 7F8F00 это только пример, не адрес

Comment: 7F8A00 я к примеру написал в качестве смещения

Comment: Вот реальный пример: Адрес откуда прыгаем 7FFBA4B7CEB4. Адрес куда прыгаем 7FFBA4E40000. Куда-откуда=2C314C

Comment: И что вам мешает сделать JMP 002C314C ?

Comment: Блин то что нужно, БЛАГОДАРЮ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо использовать косвенный `jmp near` с 4х байтной адресацией, заполнив недостающие байты 0

```
JMP 002C314C
```